# Finding the number of observations before a change in a Series occurs (pandas/numpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

Given a `Series` , I would like to efficiently compute how many observations there are before a change occurs in the series. Here is a simple example:

```
ser = pd.Series([1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,2,2,2,4,3])

print(ser)

0    1.2
1    1.2
2    1.2
3    1.2
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    4.0
8    3.0
```

I would like to apply a function to `ser` which would result in:

```
0    4
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    3
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
```

As I am dealing with large series I would prefer a fast solution that does not involve looping.

Comment: What have you tried? And how do you scan and print the input / output if the solution does not involve looping?

Comment: Please post the code that's giving you trouble.  Asking for someone else to design a solution for you is a bit beyond our expressed purpose.

Comment: I am looking for a faster code than I have. Updating now the question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a NumPy approach based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211485/3293881) -

```
def array_cumcount_descending(a):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a[1:] != a[:-1])+1
    shift_arr = -np.ones(a.size,dtype=int)

    if len(idx)>=1:
        shift_arr[0] = idx[0]
        shift_arr[idx[:-1]] = idx[1:] - idx[:-1] - 1
        shift_arr[idx[-1]] = a.size - idx[-1] - 1    
    else:
        shift_arr[0] = a.size
    return shift_arr.cumsum()
```

Sample run -

```
In [70]: ser
Out[70]: 
0    1.2
1    1.2
2    1.2
3    1.2
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    4.0
8    3.0
dtype: float64

In [71]: array_cumcount_descending(ser.values)
Out[71]: array([4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` with `cumcount`:

```
>>> ser.groupby(ser).cumcount(ascending=False)+1
0    4
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    3
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
dtype: int64
```

As per @DSM's comment, if you have multiple blocks of the same value then above will not work but you can extend the solution with:

```
>>> ser = pd.Series([1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 2, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 4, 3])
>>> ser.groupby((ser != ser.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False)+1
0     4
1     3
2     2
3     1
4     3
5     2
6     1
7     3
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: IIUC, this only works because it happens that no values in the OP's series were duplicated (discontiguously, I mean), and so grouping on the values is the same as grouping on where there's a change.

Comment: This works, thanks. Although if there happens to be a faster solution that can be great.

Comment: @splinter Without seeing your code, can't compare speed.