# Get indices of first n unique values

Tags: python, numpy, set

I have two arrays, `a` and `b` for which I would like to find the indices of the first *n* unique (across `a` and `b`) items. It's best explained with an example:

```
#               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
a = np.asarray([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])
b = np.asarray([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

For n=1, I would expect a result of `[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]` (list does not contain index=1 because that's already given by index=0 (`(a[0], b[0]) == (a[1], b[1])`), and not index=6 because that's already given by index=4 in the result list, index=9 is not included because index=8 is equivalent).

For n=2, the result should be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]` (2 unique occurrences over `a` and `b` are allowed in the result).

I'm at a loss as to how to express that in numpy... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** A pretty straight-forward with `pandas`, if you are okay with using it -

```
In [41]: import pandas as pd

In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b})

In [43]: [np.flatnonzero(df.groupby(['a','b']).cumcount()<n) for n in [1,2]]
Out[43]: 
[array([ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10]),
 array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])]
```

**Approach #2 :** For input array with `ints` and with focus on performance, we could use a *more-NumPy* version, like so -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211485/ @Divakar
def array_cumcount(a):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a[1:] != a[:-1])+1
    shift_arr = np.ones(a.size,dtype=int)
    shift_arr[0] = 0

    if len(idx)>=1:
        shift_arr[idx[0]] = -idx[0]+1
        shift_arr[idx[1:]] = -idx[1:] + idx[:-1] + 1
    return shift_arr.cumsum()

ab = a*(b.max()+1) + b
sidx = ab.argsort()
ab_s = ab[sidx]
cumcounts = array_cumcount(ab_s)[sidx]
out = [np.flatnonzero(cumcounts<n) for n in [1,2]]
```

Comment: Your numpy approach seems to be the fastest so far.

Answer (score 3):

Check with following I am using `lexsort` get the sort order via two arrays, then using `diff` and `flatnonzero` find the group which need to add the `split` point

```
ind = np.lexsort((a, b))

v=np.column_stack([a,b])

sid=np.flatnonzero(np.any(np.diff(v[ind,:].T)>0,0))+1

yourlist=np.split(np.arange(len(a))[ind], sid)

n=1
np.concatenate([x[:n]for x in yourlist])
Out[347]: array([ 0,  3,  4,  7,  8,  2, 10,  5])
```

Comment: `a.size` instead of `len(a)` would be somewhat faster and more "numpy-ish."

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 100% NumPy solution. The last step uses a list comprehension. I am not sure if a 100% NumPy solution is possible. Yet:

Combine the arrays into a 2d array:

```
ab2d = np.stack([a, b]).T
```

Find the unique values:

```
uniq = np.unique(ab2d, axis=0)
```

For each unique value, find its `N` smallest indexes in the 2d array:

```
N = 2
np.concatenate([np.argwhere((pair == ab2d).all(axis=1))[:N, 0]
                for pair in uniq])
#array([ 0,  1,  3,  2,  4,  6,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like @Divakar's 2nd approach is fastest.

```
@DYZ              1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
@Wen-Ben          1000 loops, best of 3: 234 µs per loop
@Divakar(pandas)   100 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop
@Divakar(numpy)  10000 loops, best of 3: 58.5 µs per loop
```

Tested with

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=1000, dtype=int)
b = np.random.randint(5, size=1000, dtype=int)
n = 5
```

but the conclusion also holds for smaller array sizes and values of *n*. A cursory look at @DYZ's method indicates that `np.unique` is relatively slow and so is @Wen-Ben's `np.lexsort` (the list comprehensions aren't contributing too much to runtime).